# Copy value of node using reference into other node

Tags: xslt, copy, idref

I'm trying to copy the value of an XML node referenced by an identifier into another node of the graph.
The orignal file looks like this:

```
<Root>
<Object id="Id1">
    <FileName>file.png</FileName>
</Object>
<Description>
    <Content>
        <Title>Nice Object</Title>
        <ObjectReference>Id1</ObjectReference>
    </Content>
</Description></Root>
```

In XSLT, I use a variable to identify the value of the reference node identifier.

```
<xsl:template match="Content">
<xsl:variable name="IdObject">
    <xsl:value-of select="ObjectReference"/>
</xsl:variable>
<Out>
    <Title>
        <xsl:value-of select="Title"/>
    </Title>
    <FileName>
        <xsl:value-of select="//Object[@id='$IdObject']/Filename"/>
    </FileName>
</Out></xsl:template>
```

The value of 'FileName' is not copied. I select the wrong reference node, I think. I tried with 'Ancestor::' and 'Parent::'. That doesn't work either.
Do you have an idea?
Thanks
I would like to obtain the following result :

```
<Out>
    <Name>Nice Object</Name>
    <FileName>file.png</FileName>
</Out>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XSLT has a built-in [**key**](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116/#key) mechanism for resolving cross-references. The following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="obj" match="Object" use="@id" />

<xsl:template match="Content">
    <Out>
        <xsl:copy-of select="Title"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="key('obj', ObjectReference)/FileName"/>
    </Out>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

applied to your input example, will return:

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Out>
  <Title>Nice Object</Title>
  <FileName>file.png</FileName>
</Out>
```

---

P.S. Your attempt did not work because:

1. You quoted the reference to the variable;
2. You used `Filename` instead of `FileName`.